# Amazon Web Service DynamoDB Error com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

so I am trying to connect my app to amazons cloud Nosql server DynamoDB, I have been following thier tutorial but can not seem to get it work because of this error that keeps happening:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.humber.industech.industechapp/com.humber.industech.industechapp.DataActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider.getCredentials()' on a null object reference
```

Any help on getting setup using AWS would be greatly appreciated, Thanks a lot!

Code is below:

```
public class DataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
        //setting custom font
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Prezident.ttf");
        t.setTypeface(customFont);
        saveData();
    }

     public void saveData(){
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = CredentialProviderSingleton.getInstance(this);
        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Test");
        book.setAuthor("Charles Dickens");
        book.setPrice(1299);
        book.setIsbn("1235674");
        book.setHardCover(false);
        mapper.save(book);
    }
}



public class CredentialProviderSingleton {

    static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialProvider;

    public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getInstance(Context context){
        if (credentialProvider == null){
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),"POOL_ID", Regions.US_WEST_2);
        }
        return credentialProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in the CredentialsProviderSingleton

You create a crednetials provider as a new variable

CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),"POOL_ID", Regions.US_WEST_2);

But you return the class variable credentialProvider (note it has no 's' at the end of credentials). This variable is null because it has nnever been declared.

Comment: So change CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider to credentialProvider.